# using fstream within linux

Tags: c++, linux

I think i have a beginners question.

I try to read a file line by line.

The file is in /home/myhomedir and called text.txt . 
The content of the file is

```
1
2
3
4
```

The file has access right for everyone to read and write.

I wanted: open the file and read it one line after another.

So I tried:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    try
    {
        ifstream myfile ;
        myfile.open("/home/myhomedir/text.txt", ios::in);
        if(myfile.is_open())
        {
            string line;

            while (getline(myfile, line)) {
               // do nothing, just get a line
               // *
            }
        }
    }
    catch(int ex)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The place marked with * is reached (used the debug feature of netbeans). however line is empty and loop seemed to be entered only once.

Like if an empty file is opened.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the try-catch-continue antipattern (unsuccessfully btw). I hope that's just a bad example.

Comment: Your code works well... Are you sure that your file exists ? Is it the good path ?

Comment: Could you add `cout << line << endl;` to the loop to see if this has to do with the optimizer?

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right.

Comment: @AntiClimacus the file exists with the path. as dasblinkenlight stated it seems to have to do something with optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, you don't know how to use debugger. I've modified your code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        ifstream myfile ;
        myfile.open("/home/enedil/text.txt", ios::in);
        if(myfile.is_open())
        {
            string line;

            while (getline(myfile, line)) {
                cout << line; // there's my modification
            }
        }
    }
    catch(int ex)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1234
```

So everything's correct.

Comment: then it seems to be some sort of optimization. The empty loop is only entered once will the output loop is entered multiple times. while ( myfile.good()){getline(myfile, line);} does what i want (dont ask why, the file needs to be read one time without output.)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the file is literally

```
1 2 3 4
```

then it has only one line and it is to be expected that "getline" returns false the second time it's called.